# Wordpress redirect users from certain countries to subpage of language version

Tags: redirect, ip

I would like to redirect all users from certain countries e.g from http://mydomain/subpage/ to http://mydomain/en/subpage/ ... +

So I would like to insert the "/en" between the domain and subpage, so the users do not just get thrown to the homepage if they are from a certain country, but can stay on the current page but in the respective language

Anybody know a plugin or how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done manually in `.htaccess` by creating rewrite rules.

So, for example...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]
```

This might take some tweaking but that is the gist of it.